Impresión de respuesta JSON en SpringBoot
Estoy teniendo algunos problemas con la impresión al hacer un save de JPA en SPringBoot, el registro si se guarda pero al momento de imprimir la respuesta el servidor envia un error 500 y me dice lo siguiente:

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Cannot invoke "com.TaskManager.entity.Enums.UsersRole.name()" because "this.role" is null]

El registro si se guarda pero no envia la respuesta que es del tipo entity.
Aqui les muestro la entidad en donde estoy haciendo el save()
Entity Tasks
package com.TaskManager.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import com.TaskManager.entity.Enums.TaskStatusList;
import com.TaskManager.entity.Enums.TaskType;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Tasks {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idTask;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;
    private String detail;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_id"), name = "id_user")
    private Users idUser;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private TaskType taskType;
}

El role viene de Users, aqui el código:
Entity Users
package com.TaskManager.entity;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.TaskManager.entity.Enums.UsersRole;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(
    name = "users",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name = "username_unique",
            columnNames = "username"
        ),
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name = "email_unique",
            columnNames = "email"
        )
    }
)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Users implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Long id_user;

    @Column(length = 25)
    private String document;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String lastname;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please, add an username")
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please, add a password")
    @Length(min = 6)
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "Please, add an email")
    private String email;

    private String phone;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creation_date;
    
    /*
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_rol_id"), name = "id_rol")
    private UsersRol rol;
    */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private UsersRole role;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate(){
        creation_date = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}

El role es un Enum sencillo con 4 opciones:
package com.TaskManager.entity.Enums;

public enum UsersRole {
    SUPERADMIN,
    ADMIN,
    USER,
    SUPPORT_USER
}

Al realizar el save() de Tasks debería devolver el JSON con los datos almacenados en el servidor pero me da ese error.

Ya encontré una forma de solucionarlo. Lo que hice fue crear un objeto Users manual con el id que se envia en el objeto Tasks, con esto garantizo que no sea null, el código sería algo como el siguiente:
var user = usersRepository.findById(task.getIdUser().getId_user()).get();

        var newTask = tasksRepository.save(task);
        newTask.setIdUser(user);

Con esto busco el usuario y lo inyecto en la respuesta del servidor y asi me aseguro que no venga null.
Se que no es la forma más óptima, agradezco si alguien sabe una mejor forma de hacerlo para implementarla
